# How to differentiate between pass and fail using extent reports in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two test methods and I wrote some code to verify title of the link.In one method I have deliberately passed one method and failed the other one but in the report it gives pass status only in pie chart. How to track the failed one ?
Below is my code:

```
    package com.custom.reports;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;

public class CustomReports {
    WebDriver driver;
    ExtentReports logger;

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void verifyTitle() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        logger = ExtentReports.get(CustomReports.class);
        logger.init("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Documents\\Reports\\SecondReport.html", true);
        logger.startTest("Verify Title Test");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Browser is up and running..");
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Application is up and running..");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Google"));
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Title is verified..");
        logger.endTest();

    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void verifyTitle2() {
        String title1 = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertTrue(title1.contains("Selenium"));
        logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Title is verified..");
        logger.endTest();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterFailed() { 
        driver.get("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Documents\\Reports\\SecondReport.html");
    }
}
```

and below is the screenshot of the report generated:
[image]
Please let me know if any additional information is required.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I´d say that your question is more Testng relevant that it is Selenium. We work with Junit, hence a comment instead of an answer. In one of the projects we have, we added a `@Rule` and did `@Override protected void succeeded(Description description){}` and `@Override protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description){}`.

Comment: okay @EnriqueMedina .Do you have any idea how can i achieve it in TestNG ?

Comment: anybody help please

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar Did this Question got Answered or you are still awaiting an Answer?

Comment: no it has not been answered yet. I mean i haven't got my solution what I am looking for .Still open. Help me @Dev if you can :(

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar Can you update me your `ExtentReport` jar version please? I think you can bump upto the stable ExtentReport v2.05 release and update me the status. Thanks

Comment: i am using 1.4 version and if I use version 2 and above I am not able to create object of ExtentReports . I mean this line : logger = ExtentReports.get(CustomReports.class);

Comment: @SiddheshKalgaonkar Its pretty clear from your code you mixed up `ExtentReport 1.x` & `ExtentReport 2.x` styles :) What is your requirement?

Comment: Okay , I want pass and fail result in that shown pie chart report but its showing result of first passed test method only . So how can I achieve it ?

Comment: `ExtentReport 1.4` right?

Comment: yes or any other way will also do but i need both pass and fail in pie chart

Answer (score 0):

Get it to check the result after each method.

```
@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result){
    if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
    // Stuff
    }
    report.endTest(logger);
}
```

Comment: can you give me more clarity on how to edit this code .that would seriously help and there is no report variable in my code . Where did you find it ?

Comment: I wrote my code a long while ago.

in BeforeTest, it will create a report
 report = new ExtentReports("PATH");

The in Test, it will start it
 logger = report.startTest("Test");

So in AfterMethod (So after each Test) it will pull ITestResult from the test in Test. 
result.getStatus() should be a form of ITestResult.RESULTTYPE

Comment: logger is object of ExtentReports only .can you please modify your code and write it in detail because that way would really help

Answer (score 0):

I believe we need to start and end test for each @Test (logging as separate test in extent). In the code i could see, the test logging has been started and ended for only verifyTitle()(first test method) and it has three logs for info.

Thus the report is showing only one test case passed(first test method) along with three info (Three info logs are in first test method).

Kindly try adding start/end test for all test methods and check.

Below is the modified code.

```
public class Stack
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    ExtentReports logger = ExtentReports.get(CustomReports.class); //Initinating the logger
    logger.init("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Documents\\Reports\\SecondReport.html", true);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

@Test(priority = 1)
public void verifyTitle() 
{

    logger.startTest("Verify Title Test");//Starting the test logger
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Browser is up and running..");
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Application is up and running..");
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Google")); //This will pass
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Title is verified..");
    logger.endTest();//Ending the test logger

}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void verifyTitle2() 
{

    logger.startTest("Verify Failing the test case");//Starting the test logger
    String title1 = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(title1.contains("Selenium")); //This will fail
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Title is verified..");
    logger.endTest();//Ending the test logger
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterFailed() 
{ 
    driver.get("C:\\Users\\siddhesh.kalgaonkar\\Documents\\Reports\\SecondReport.html");
}
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah i edited that one too but still the same.I have updated my code .please have a look

Comment: We need to start and end the extent test logger for each @Test. If we start the test at method1 and end it in method 2, then it will consider both method1 and method2 as a single test. Also i can see you are failing the test case in After Suite... but we dont have any test logger started for After suite. In the current  case, i believe you got 4 info's in the pie chart

Comment: thanks @santhosh .I got you this time and i have edited my code and now its showing in console passed and failed result but in report it is not showing  for failed one .

Comment: Failed won't be shown in report because you have failed the after suite... Extent will consider only the @Test in Report generation.

Comment: so what i need to do here ?

Comment: can i get your objective please?

Comment: I want to show both pass and fail in mentioned pie chart .so for it what changes should be made in the above code?

Comment: Thanks santhosh now it shows pass as 2 methods even though 1 has failed but its showing in green pie chart only whereas in console it is showing passed and failed result